# How to add confidence interval VALUES on an Excel graph?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I've created a "stacked line with markers" on Excel. Is there a way to label each marker point with its confidence interval values? The confidence intervals are so large than showing them visually doesn't really make sense (can't really see trends anymore).

Thank you

Comment: Insert data labels and use "Value from Cells" to get the confidence intervals from whatever range they are in. If that doesn't do the job, it may be useful if you could [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1701976/edit) to add some sample data and a link to a screencap of your chart. (you can upload the screencap to http://imgur.com)

Answer (score 0):

**:Caveat:** *Since your post doesn't have any sample data therefore I've used this one.*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Select N42:O46 & Plot Slaked Line With Markers chart.
- Now select the chart area, hit Plus sign.
- Click Error Bars next hit More Options.
- Now select Custom, and use Q42:Q46.
- Format Error Bar will appear.
- Select Direction & End Style as needed (currently is Plus).
- You may apply Color to them.

**N.B.**

- To calculate Margin Of Error, use an appropriate formula.
- I've used formula in cell Q43: `=P43-O43`.
- Adjust cell references as needed.